# Can I install elementary OS 0.4 Loki?

Tags: system-installation

I see on [Launchpad that there is release 0.4 Loki](https://launchpad.net/elementaryos/0.4-loki). Is this available for download?

If so, is it the same installation (i.e. with an ISO) or is it a more technical process?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, elementary OS Loki has been released. For the latest version of elementary OS, you can always visit [elementary.io](https://elementary.io).

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: These directions are unofficial, outdated, and not supported by elementary**

First, download Ubuntu 16.04 from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/ and install it. Then in Ubuntu 16.04 terminal run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop
```

Then you should be able to select the new desktop environment in the Unity greeter.

Source : https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/49k2xp/how_to_preview_loki_ubuntu_1606_dailyospatches_ppa/

Maybe someone can make an ISO from this.

Comment: This is *not* going to give you something that works like elementary OS Loki, and we never encourage users to add daily repositories, especially on top of another OS install. This is very likely to break in spectacular and unpredictable ways.

Comment: @CassidyJames Yes , it is not official and may break things.How does the elementary OS developer team test Loki?

Comment: The developers of elementary OS test it using daily build ISOs that are not released to the general public. Once a beta release is ready, it will be announced at blog.elementary.io.

Comment: How can I build the ISO

Answer (score 1):

Loki beta is available for installation and can be found at https://elementary.io/developer.

Consider the limitations inherent to a testing release, described [here](http://blog.elementary.io/post/147507276666/loki-beta-2-is-here).

Comment: Will Loki Beta 2 be able to be upgraded once the public release is out?

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović - I personally don't know, I think probably not, but you should create a question here on that. Or I could, if you prefer. If you do create the question, please let me know with a comment here.